# IIS can not read site configurations from UNC path

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I created a site in my IIS server `(Server A)`, and the site's physical path is located in a share folder (UNC path e.g: `\\server b\mysite\`). 
server A and B are in same domain.
the site application pool identity is set to built-in account `network service`.

When I want to edit something in IIS for this site, I get the following error:

```
The was an error while performing this operation.
Details
Filename: \\?UNC\server b\mysite
Error: cannot read configuration files
```

So I gave full control permission to: `server a$` and `network service` to this share folder. but I still get same message.
Which permission should I give to that folder in order to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the authentication setup of the site?

Comment: @LexLi anonymous authentication

Comment: Go to IIS Manager and change anonymous account for this site to use application pool identity. That might resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok I resolved this by setting `connect as` property in site `basic setting` property.